Why there's no matrix chernoff for other matrix norm, such as nuclear norm?
I've read lots of concentration inequalities for matrices, as listed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_Chernoff_bound, where they focus on how the spectral norm of a random matrix derive from its expectation. So my question is, is there any concentration inequalties for other norm, such as nuclear norm? If they doesn't exist, why?
